# CLRS Exercise 24.3-4 - Confirm Output of a Program Claiming to Implement Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

I'm trying to better understand Question 24.3-4 From CLRS below:

> Professor Gaedel has written a program that he claims implements Dijkstra’s algorithm.
>   The program produces $v.d$ and $v.\pi$ for each vertex $v \in V$. Give an
>   $O(V + E)$ algorithm to check the output of the professor’s program. It should
>   determine whether the $d$ and $\pi$ attributes match those of some shortest-paths tree.
>   You may assume that all edge weights are non-negative.

I have the answer from the Solutions manual, but simply do not understand how this answer actually works: (bottom of pg. 5/19, **Exercise 24.3-4** didn't want to overload the question with a long solution):
https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~ajl213/CLRS/Ch24.pdf

Basically, the solution says we have to check every edge $(u, v)$ for all $v \neq s$. I understand that we only need to ensure that $s.d = 0$ and $s.\pi = NIL$ since the $\delta(s, s) = 0$ and $s$ should not have a predecessor, as it is the first vertex in the graph. The solution goes on to mention that:

> "Check that $v.\pi$ is the vertex which minimizes $u.d +w(u, v)$ for all vertices $u$ for which there is an edge $(u, v)$, and that $v.d = v.π.d + w(v.π, v)$. If this is ever false, return false"

So I understand that for any $v \neq s$ that $v.\pi.d < v.d$ by the fact that $v.d = v.\pi.d + w(v.pi, v)$ so the distance of any node's predecessor must always be less than that of the node by the simple property.

***How do we manage to check though that***: "$v.\pi$ is the vertex which minimizes $u.d +w(u, v)$ for all vertices $u$ for which there is an edge $(u, v)$?"

Since say we pick some random vertex in the graph that is a neighbor of $s$, call this node $v$. So $\delta(s, v)$ could potentially be calculated by traversing half of the graph then coming back to $v$ through some other node, $u$ if the $w(s, v)$ is extremely large. How does the algorithm verify cases like this? Does it ensure that it starts **only** at the neighbors of $s$ first, verify those distances, and essentially inductively proceed to verify the remaining predecessors and distances?

It seems that for $v \in V - {s}$ that if $v.\pi$ is correct, then all that remains is to verify $v.d$? I just don't really understand how the algorithm can correctly do this.. Is it traversing the graph, or iterating over the adjacency list/set of edges for each node, such that for a node, $v$ we check **all** edges $(u, v)$ somehow and then come up with an understanding of whether the node $v$ has the proper $v.\pi$?

Could someone please help/explain how this solution works? Have been struggling for a few hours now on this, and stepped through the algorithm with written examples but am not seeing the pattern here. Thank you.

**Edit** I've seen some answers mentioning creating a tree (since Dijkstra's algorithm is supposed to output a shorted path tree from the src node, $s$).

Regarding this: Would we create a shortest path tree using all of the $v.\pi$ values for each $v \in V - \{s\}$, since $s.\pi = NIL$? This takes time $O(V + E)$ to create an adjacency list we would need to traverse using BFS/DFS. Then, we begin a DFS on the tree created by the $v.\pi$ attributes and modify the DFS to check $v.d = v.\pi.d + w(v.\pi.d + v)$ or something along these lines?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to go out on a limb with this one and attempt to answer my own question. It seems that when running the algorithm given in the solution, say that there are many vertices for which $v.\pi$ and $v.d$ is incorrect (call this set of vertices, $V_i$ and $V_i \subseteq V$).

When we run the algorithm, if there are at least **some** vertices for which $v.\pi$ and $v.d$ is correct (call this set of vertices $V_c$ and $V_c \subseteq V$), the algorithm is guaranteed to detect at some point that there is an incorrect vertex $u$, such that $u \in V_i$.

But, it **may return a false positive** for some vertex, $u$ (again such that $u \in V_i$) if all of the parents of $u$, WLOG say a parent($u$), is called $p$, so $p$ also has incorrect distance and predecessor values, thus $p.\pi$ and $p.d$ is incorrect for a parent, $p$ of $u$ therefore $p \in V_i$ but eventually we will come across some vertex $u \in V_i$ such that when we look at the incoming edges to $u$, we will find that $u.\pi$ is incorrect, since at least $1$ of the parents of $u$, call it $p' \in V_c$ has correct distance and predecessor values, and we would return false/something that indicates we have found the vertex $u$ such that $u.\pi$ and $u.d$ are incorrect.

In the case of all $v \in V$ outputted by the Professor's program are incorrect, we'd easily find a $v$ such that $s \xrightarrow{} v$ and see that $v.\pi$ or $v.d$ is incorrect.

I believe this explains how the algorithm works... Someone please correct me where/if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the right idea, but your answer is a little imprecise, so I'll give my best bid in the hope that it helps someone.

Let the source (root) of the shortest path tree be named $s$.

Firstly, I'm going to assume that the tree encoded by the $v.\pi$ and $v.d$ values is internally consistent. That is, there are no loops and $v.d$ ($v$'s distance estimate) is equal to the weight of the path from $s$ to $v$. This is easy to check in linear time. Given this assumption an incorrect distance estimate will be too large as opposed to too small; You can't find a shorter path than the shortest path, and the distance estimate is consistent with the path.

Secondly, I'd like to promote describing algorithms in a simpler way whenever possible, and save heavy mathematical notation for when it is needed. In the context of CLRS, "relaxing" an edge is meaningful, so a simpler way to describe the algorithm is:

> Relax all the edges in the graph. If any distance estimate changes or if the distance estimate of the source is not zero, return that the input is not a shortest path tree. Otherwise, return that it is.

Now to prove the correctness of the algorithm.

**An edge was successfully relaxed $\rightarrow $ the input is wrong:**

Since some $v.d$ changed to something smaller, you discovered a shorter $s \leadsto v$ path, so the input must be wrong.

**The input is wrong $\rightarrow $ an edge will be relaxed successfully:**

Let $v$ be a closest vertex to $s$ which has an incorrect distance estimate. The last node $u$ before $v$ on the shortest $s\leadsto v$ path is closer to $s$ than $v$ is (because edge weights are positive) and so $u.d$ is correct (by the choice of $v$ as the closest). The edge $(u,v)$ will be relaxed, and the shortest $s \leadsto v$ path will be found, changing $v.d$.

From the above we can see that an edge will be relaxed successfully if and only if the input is incorrect, and thus the algorithm must be correct.

**(I just realized this proof only works when edge weights are strictly positive, as opposed to non-negative. But I think adapting it shouldn't be too hard)**